# Compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I really don't know how solve this problem:

Let $V$ be the space of real functions spanned by $\cos(x)$, $\cos(2x)$ and $\cos(3x)$. Let $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,V)$ con $T(\cos(x)) = 3\cos(x) + 2\cos(2x) - \cos(3x)$, $\;T(\cos(2x)) = 3\cos(2x) + \cos(3x)$ and $T(\cos(3x)) = \cos(3x)$. Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$.

Please, I need help

Thanxs in advance.

Comment: Find out the matrix of the operator $T$ in the given basis and compute the eigenvalues of that matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear that
$$T\left(\begin{array}{c}\cos(x)\\\cos(2x)\\\cos(3x)\end{array}\right)\ =\ \underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{ccc}3 & 2 & -1 \\0 & 3 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)}_{A}\left(\begin{array}{c}\cos(x)\\\cos(2x)\\\cos(3x)\end{array}\right)$$
where $A$ have the eigenvalues 1, 3 and 3. Later,

1. You have that $T(\cos(3x)) = \cos(3x)$, and then $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with eigenvector $v_1 = \cos(3x)$.
2. Now, if $v_2 = \alpha\cos(x) + \beta\cos(2x) + \gamma\cos(3x)$ is an eigenvector of $T$ for eigenvector $3$, then
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   T(v_2) & = & 3v_2,\\
   \alpha T(\cos(x)) + \beta T(\cos(2x)) + \gamma T(\cos(3x)) & = & 3\alpha\cos(x) + 3\beta\cos(2x) + 3\gamma\cos(3x),\\
   3\alpha\cos(x) + (2\alpha + 3\beta)\cos(2x) - (\alpha - \beta - \gamma)\cos(3x) & = & 3\alpha\cos(x) + 3\beta\cos(2x) + 3\gamma\cos(3x),\\
   2\alpha\cos(2x) - (\alpha - \beta + 2\gamma)\cos(3x) & = & 0.
   \end{eqnarray*}
   Now, $\cos(2x)$ and $\cos(3x)$ are linear independent, then you have
   $2\alpha = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha = 0$ and $\alpha - \beta +2\gamma = 0 \Rightarrow \beta = 2\gamma$. Therefore
   $$v_2\ =\ \gamma\left[2\cos(2x) + \cos(3x)\right],\quad \gamma \in \mathbb{K}$$
   is an eigenvector for 3.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix representation of your linear transformation can be written as:

$$ A:= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}3 & 2 & -1 \\0 & 3 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right) $$

Since the matrix is triangular the characteristic polynomial can be easily read off by looking at $ \det( xI-A)$. Can you proceed now with what you need to show?

Comment: Actually, the matrix is $$A:= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}3 & 2 & -1 \\0 & 3 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right), $$ and its eigenvalues are 1, 3 and 3. With eigenvectors $(1,-2,4)^T$ and $(1,0,0)^T$. But what is the eigenvectors of $T$? For example, I can see that $\cos(3x)$ is an eigenvector for $1$, but I don't know an eigenvector of $3$. Thanxs

Comment: Please, note that $T:V\rightarrow V$ and $V\not\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$. Later, the eigenvector of $A$ are in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then what happend with the eigenvectors of $T$ in $V$?